# Help with work on collatz conjecture?

Tags: graphing-functions, collatz-conjecture

I've managed to rearrange the collatz conjecture into a formulae and was wondering if I'm going in the right direction?

The Formulae:

$y=\left(3\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)x\right)\right)+\left(1\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\right)\right)\ +\ \left(\frac{x\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\ -\ \left(\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\right)\right)\ +\ \left(\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x+1,2\right)\right)\right)\right)}{2}\right)$

I've graphed this out and it works out to following the conjecture. However, I have no idea how to prove the x->...->4->2->1 cycle, although it's very evident in the graph. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want us to help you turn this into a proof of the collatz conjecture? Would you then be so kind as to share with us a small fraction of your prize money?

Comment: @EarthCracks i mean if you managed to, i'd love to know about it (and of course, if I won the prize money, I'd share it with anyone who helped, though it's very unlikely i'll be able to prove it). I'm just wondering whether i'm going in the right direction, whether this has any mistakes and how i could go about proving that it follows the x->...->4->2->1 cycle

Comment: I am not sure why do you need $\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\ -\ \left(1\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\right)\right)$ and why you need this $1$ multipliers? Anyway, your question is equivalent to "how to prove Collatz conjecture", and I doubt anyone knows the answer now.

Comment: @mihaild oh right you have a point with the "1" multipliers, and oh right, fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulae is just a rendering of the Collatz map.

It produces the following sequence:
$$0,4,1,10,2,16,3,22,4,28,5,...$$

See https://oeis.org/A006370.

Im not sure if you are going into the right direction, since yours is a more difficult to comprehend formula. But of course manipulating the Collatz function is a way to learn and understand the underlying mechanics of it. What do you mean its evident in the graph? Visualizing the Collatz graph in on itself is not a proof.

By the way your formula would become:

$$\frac{xw}{2}+v$$

where

$$x(z-z+w) = xw$$

and

$$w=3xz$$